# JQuery Datepicker not triggering .prop('disabled')

Tags: jquery, datepicker, keyup

Morning,

I just started messing around with datepicker.  Everything is going well, but in one of my forms I say

```
\$('#datepicker3').keyup(function() {
                                    if (\$(this).val() != '')
                                            \$('#dayswaived').prop("disabled", true);
                                    else
                                            \$('#dayswaived').prop("disabled", false);
                            });
```

If I manually type into the field, is triggers the condition, and the other field is disabled.  If I use datepicker, the condition never fires.  I also tried blur but with no success.

Any ideas on this?  I did some looking around before asking this question.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-dialog) callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See for change event instead:

```
$('#datepicker3').change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() != '')
          $('#dayswaived').prop("disabled", true);
     else
          $('#dayswaived').prop("disabled", false);
}).keyup(function(){$(this).change()});
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XM5Q6/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use roasted's example or you can use the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-dialog) callback.

```
function check(){
    $('#dayswaived').prop("disabled", this.value != '')
};
$('#datepicker3').datepicker({onSelect:check}).keyup(check);
```

Also there's really no need for the if/else because you can pass the condition right into the prop method.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZCLj/)